# break out of if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, break, goto

If I was doing purely functional programming I could probably do an early return, but in this case I want to break out of an if-statement early, something like this:

```
const doSomeWork = (resp, json) => {

  if (json && json[CPStorageKeys.CP_AUTH_TOKEN]) {
    const tokenFromBody = json[CPStorageKeys.CP_AUTH_TOKEN];

    if (typeof tokenFromBody !== 'string') {
      break breakto; // break out of if statement to goto the label below
    }

    if (tokenFromBody && tokenFromBody.length < 80) {
      console.error('Token length from response body is too short.');
    } else if (tokenFromBody) {
      if (tokenFromBody != tokenFromHeader) {
        console.warn('token from header does not match token from body:', tokenFromHeader, tokenFromBody)
      }
      console.log('user auth token:', tokenFromBody);
      cpStorage.set(CPStorageKeys.CP_AUTH_TOKEN, tokenFromBody);
    }
  }

  breakto: {};

  return [resp, json];

}
```

but I don't know how to break out of the if block early using labels, anyone know a good way to do this that won't make me hate my own code later?!

Comment: You need a label before the first `if` so that you can `break` by referencing it.

Comment: I would just invert the `if` condition, and put the rest of the code in the body.

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you show an example as an answer?

Comment: See the linked question.